# Reactjs call componentWillMount of parent component

Tags: javascript, oop, reactjs

I have two components as below:

```
class Parent
{
  componentWillMount () {
    console.log('parent componentWillMount');
  }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
  componentWillMount () {
    console.log('child componentWillMount');
  }
}
```

But when the child component is loaded the componentWillMount method of the parent component is not loaded automatically. How do you call componentWillMount method of the parent component ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to access the parent's componentWillMount? Basing on react's render tree, it is not necessary to 're-render' parent if child component will be render again

Comment: I would suggest not doing this sort of inheritance with React components. In theory you could call `super.componentWillMount()` I think but that's not good practice. https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/571278443712794625?lang=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
      class Child extends Parent
      {
        componentWillMount () {
          super.componentWillMount() ; //parent componentWillMount
          console.log('child componentWillMount');
        }
      }
```

explain :

`Child#componentWillMount` overrides `Parent#componentWillMount`. So :

- if you need only logic of `Parent#componentWillMount` without adding extra-logic, it is recommended to remove `componentWillMount` from `Child` .
- If you need to call `Parent#componentWillMount` with appending some logic, retain `Child#componentWillMount` and call inside it `super.componentWillMount();`

Answer (score -1):

You can call a parent's method in the follow manner:

```
class Child extends Perent {
    componentWillMount () {
        super.componentWillMount();

        // Insert your child specific code here
     }
 }
```

But as [Ben Nyrberg already mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092571/reactjs-call-componentwillmount-of-parent-component/42092848#comment71355636_42092571) **it's not a good practice**.

**The good practice** of reusing components code by following the React way is with **components composition**:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        // Reusable functionality here
    }

    render() {
        return {this.props.children}
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        // Child specific functionality
    }

    render() {
        return <div>Whatever you want</div>
    }
}


class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Parent>
           <Child />
        </Parent>
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess there's a typo: `super()` calls `Parent`'s constructor, not the same method.

Comment: Yep, it was a typo. Thanks. Now it's fixed! :)